# How to convert javascript object variable into a class

Tags: javascript

How do I define a class I can instatiate later?

I wrote myself a rotator class using jquery which looks like:

```
var Rotator =
{
Loop: null,

init: function(identifierName)
    {
    ........
    }
}
```

If i want to have one rotator on my page it's good. I just call `Rotator.init()` and it's ready.
However when I want to have 3 rotators i got to define 3 times the whole class code  changing its name.

Way easier it would be if I could just do

```
  Instance1 = new rotator;
  Instance2 = new rotator;
  Instance3 = new rotator;
```

Comment: [this might be useful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide%2FDetails_of_the_Object_Model#Class-Based_vs._Prototype-Based_Languages)

Comment: Thx, clears bit more :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is what your object literal might look like as a re-usable Named Function that can be instantiated multiple times:

```
var Rotator = function(name) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Loop = null;

    this.init = function(identifierName)
    {
        this.Name = identifierName;
    };
};

// usage:

var foorotator = new Rotator('foo');
var barrotator = new Rotator('bar');

alert(foorotator.Name);
alert(barrotator.Name);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JzWCL/

**After Edit:**

http://jsfiddle.net/mPzsq/

Comment: `Rotator.prototype.init = function(identifierName){/***/}` [2. Using object literals](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/)

Comment: @ejay yes, thanks for pointing out that `function`s in JavaScript are also objects which have a `prototype` property which allows for prototypal inheritance.

Comment: oh. so you can't create a class like in PHP. You got to create function and add subfunctions.... ::sick::
So if I used this example. How do I (being in this.init function) call to the thix.Loop ? If you could extend it so init function sets value of this.Name I would be gratefull!

Comment: No idea why. First instance is working good. When I create 2nd instance consolse says: TypeError: Rotator is not a constructor
Rotator2 = new Rotator('b');

Answer (score 2):

Xander's solution looks like an acceptable form for a class-like object used only once. If you plan to subclass or multiply instantiate it, however, you should apply methods to the prototype rather than defining them within the main class (constructor) function. For example:

```
var Rotator = function(name) {
    //run your initialization logic inside this constructor function
    this.Name = name;
    this.Loop = null;
}

Rotator.prototype.someMethod = function() {
    //method code
}

var rotator1 = new Rotator('foo');
var rotator2 = new Rotator('bar');
```

The reason to use this structure is to prevent the methods from being reconstructed every time the class is instantiated. By applying the methods to the prototype, they will be shared between all instances of the class.

I've found this to be a helpful reference for some basics of JavaScript class definition:
[3 Ways to Define a JavaScript Class](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/)